# Freezing const variables completely

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

Looking at the below code, I found a strange and seemingly bad problem with `const`:

```
const path = require('path');


function reWritePath() {

    let path = 'blah';

    console.log(path);
}


reWritePath();
```

This seems to go against the point of `const`, and I'm surprised to find it can be rewritten in subscopes. Is there a clean way to completely freeze a variable so this can't happen anywhere across the file?

Comment: function creates a new scope, hence, you can define same variable again in this scope again. You can use `=>` function to maintain a scope or use `reWritePath.call(this)` to maintain the scope in the calling function

Comment: The purpose of scopes is to define distinct spaces where names can be bound to variables without interfering with other scopes. A nested scope is yet another scope with its own name resolution. Besides, do you really want to introduce a global `path` variable as a dependency for `reWritePath`?

Comment: The behaviour you are looking for would be really weird. We could not write functions with local variables without knowing all global variables, or risk colliding with their names.

Comment: So this isn't recommended to do at all? @Bergi

Comment: @codyc4321 No, it's fine to have a convention that requires unique variable names across certain compilation units - and a linter can help you enforce it. I just meant to say that it's a language *feature* to have different variables with the same name in different scopes, which encourages modularity and makes local reasoning easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are not the same variables. The same *names*, yes, but in different scopes.

There is no way of strictly not allowing this to happen -- [instead, you should use a linter that can look for name shadowing](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-shadow) so you'll at least notice this happening.

Answer (score 0):

AKX is right - there are really two separate variables named `path`. They just happen to have the same name.

Consider this:

```
const x = 0;

function reWritePath() {
    let x = 1;
    console.log(x);
}

reWritePath();
console.log(x);
```

The output of this will be:

```
1
0
```

If that's confusing, try renaming one of the variables:

```
const x = 0;

function reWritePath() {
    let y = 1;
    console.log(y);
}

reWritePath();
console.log(x);
```